# ManagementForm data missing error while formset validation

Tags: django, validation, django-forms, formset

formset creation in views.py:

```
ffact = formset_factory(Form,extra=somenum]))
fset = ffact(prefix='pfix')
```

validation in views.py:

```
ffact = formset_factory(Form,extra=3))
fset = ffact(request.POST) 
if fset_is.valid():
    blah blah
```

this is resulting in Exception Type: ValidationError at /app/index/
Exception Value: [u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']  [django-docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform)
did mention about this. I'm not sure how to provide management data. I tried something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536285/django-formset-management-form-validation-error) ,

```
try:
  fset = ffact(request.POST)
except ValidationError:
  fset = None
if fset and fset.is_valid():
  blah blah
```

But still i get the same error.Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The Django-docs link you provide is outdated. Here are two alternatives:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform
and
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-the-formset-in-the-template

Answer (score 8, accepted):

rendering the formset.management_form in the template

```
{{fset.management_form}}
```

this allows the management form data available and hence data is complete.But if prefix is added while genarating formsets

adding prefix should fix that issue.

```
fset = ffact(request.POST,prefix='pfix')
```

Answer (score 8):

Is the management data in `request.POST`?
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform

The following info has to be in `request.POST`:

```
data = {
    'form-TOTAL_FORMS': u'1',
    'form-INITIAL_FORMS': u'0',
    'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': u'',
}
```

There is a shortcut for rendering the hidden fields: `{{ my_formset.management_form }}`

Comment: am sorry i dint get it.Yea i did refer to that document.What I'm not sure is how i can provide the extra info its lookin for?